# Animate depending if input box is empty and stay there?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I am trying to make an input box that looks like it has a placeholder that says username, but when the box is selected it moves and changes to a darker color to resemble a label. The problem I am having is whenever I hover over the  box it will complete the animation but then immediately undo it, putting the text back to look like a placeholder. I also want to make my Javascript/JQuery code so that if the box has any typing in it that the text will stay as a label and not go back to being the placeholder even without being selected. My other problem is that I do not know the JQuery command to tell if an input box is selected or not. I supply all my code below along with a link to CodePen which has the

```
<div id='inputdiv'>
  <input id='textinp'>
</div>
<h4>Username</h4>
```

```
#textinp {
  border: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

#inputdiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 70px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  z-index: -2;
}

h4 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 53px;
  left: 575px;
  color: #C2C2C2;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inputdiv").mouseenter(function() {
    $("h4").animate({
      left: '470px',
      color: '#00000'
    });
    if ($('#textinp').val() == '') {
      $("h4").animate({
        left: '580px',
        color: '#C2C2C2'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/JoshuaHurlburt/pen/qOKaOb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `hover()` method instead. As first parameter define function to be executed on hoverIn (on mouse entering), as second - function to be executed on hoverOut (on mouse leaving).

Here's your example updated:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LprybQ

Comment: Thank you that basically solved it. The only other problem is that when I click on the box and then start typing well I am not hovering over it then the Username will go back over the input box. If there was a JQuery command to like .focus() or something that would tell when an input box is selected I think it would solve the problem, or maybe I could move the if statement somewhere else and it might. Thank you for your help!